# Missing C++20 headers on Ubuntu 20.04 with Clang 13

Tags: c++, cmake, clang, c++20, libstdc++

I have installed clang-13, but when I try to compile a program that uses C++20 headers, I get missing header errors.

```cpp
#include <numeric>  
#include <numbers> // missing
```

It seems that CMake uses the system headers (from the old GCC headers shipped with ubuntu). How do I convince it to use the Clang's headers instead?

Numbers header is part of C++20
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/numbers

Comment: Either install a new libstdc++ (by installing a new GCC; Clang should find it automatically) or install libc++. The former is the default, the latter needs `-stdlib=libc++`.

Comment: So this means that clang doesn't include a new libstdc++ and the only way to upgrade libstdc++ is to install a new gcc. Am I right?

Comment: Libstdc++ is a C++ standard library of GCC, so it's a part of the GCC project, not Clang. Yep, it needs to be installed separately. There's probably a package that lets you install it without a new GCC, but it's easier to just install GCC. libc++, on the other hand, is Clang's own standard library (which also needs to be installed separately).

Comment: Where is your clang-13 package installed from? Is it [one of these](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/focal/+package/clang-13)? Because it looks like all of those depend on `libstdc++-9-dev`, so wouldn't it get automatically installed for you? (I know very little about ubuntu so I could be spouting total nonsense here).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installing the latest version of g++ fixed the issue for me. For example, g++-11 is the latest version at the moment. To install it on Ubuntu:

Add the toolchain ppa to ensure that the latest version is available:

```
sudo add-apt-repository --update -y ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
sudo apt-get update -y
```

Then install

```
sudo apt-get -y --fix-broken install gcc-11 g++-11
```

You can check for the latest version here:
[https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-toolchain-r/+archive/ubuntu/test](https://launchpad.net/%7Eubuntu-toolchain-r/+archive/ubuntu/test)